# Refresh an image that is uploaded every 60 seconds to a specific location (same file name)

Tags: javascript, html

First, this is the live website in question: https://severnlodge.com/about-us/webcam/

This is the juryrigged script we are using:

```js
var t = 60 // interval in seconds 
image1 = "https://severnlodge.com/wp-content/webcam/webcam.jpg" //name of the image

function Start() { 
    tmp = new Date(); 
    tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime() 
    document.images["refresh1"].src = image1+tmp 
    setTimeout("Start()", t*1000) 
} 
Start();
```

```html
<header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate')>
<img src="https://severnlodge.com/wp-content/webcam/webcam.jpg" alt="Severn Lodge Webcam - T-dock" width="100%" name="refresh1"/>
```

We have a client who has two webcams that upload an image (webcam.jpg or webcam2.jpg) every 60 seconds. The images are about 150kb each and override the prior image upon being uploaded. We are trying to produce a page that displays these two images and refreshes both images roughly every 60 seconds.

Now this *mostly* works.  Except for sometimes when it loads either webcam.jpg or webcam2.jpg it will display a broken image link or a partial image.  I assume this is because the refresh is trying to load the image before it's fully updated?  I am not a coder, but I have been tasked with trying to figure this out...

So is there a type of code to make sure the file is "completely uploaded" before it tries to load?  Or a way where if the image breaks, it tries again immediately?

Please excuse my lack of knowledge, this type of thing is normally out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: I would look for threads related to 'preloading' images.  My first thought would be in the case that the image is broken, the `load` event might not fire.  If that is true, then if you relied on the load event to happen before you updated the page, you could safeguard against it potentially like that.

Comment: And sometimes the image will also not load due to any specific internet issue or any reason. At that time you need to handle